# How to use AWS lambda in VS code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

First of all, we installed awscli & IAM user create.

And, Created credentials profile in VS Code
It is connect to aws toolkit in profile and VS Code.

Successful deployment attempt.

But how can I use AWS lambda?

**Code to be used for AWS Lambda**

```
import requests
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/"
f = requests.get(url)
print(f)
```

**Setting for AWS toolkit in vs code is over.**
[image]

> How to use crawling code in vs code?

Comment: Have you check how to write lambda functions in Python using [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python.html)?